# Finding subgraph from a graph in OrientDb

Tags: graph, neo4j, orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop

This is my graph

```
[Person] -livesIn->  [City]
[Factory] -locatedIn-> [City]
[Person] -worksAt-> [Factory]
```

**How do I find people who have to travel far for work. i.e. "People working at at factory that is not located in the city they are living in".?**

I tried to do this:

```
Match 
    {class:Person, as: person} -worksAt-> {class:Factory, as: factory} -locatedIn-> {class:City, as: city},
    {how do i check, person !livesIn city }
return person
```

I don't think this problem is specific to orinentDb, so feel free to let me know how one can solve this in any other graphDb.

I'm familiar with SQL dialect of OrientDb & Gremlin too.
A direction/help in any of the languages is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about something like:

Match (c:Company)<-[:WorksFor]-(p:Person)-[:LivesIn]->(t:City)

Where NOT (c)-[:LocatedIn]->(t)

Return p

The fields are a little bit different and this is written in cypher.

Comment: No.. So the equivalent query in OrientDb is returning nothing.

    Match 
         {class: City, as: c} <-livesIn- {class: Person, as: p} -worksAt-> {class: Factory, as: f},
         NOT {as: f} -locatedAt-> {as: c}
    return $pathElements


Something about "NOT" i think i'm not using it right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Match 
    {class:Person, as: person} -worksAt-> {class:Factory, as: factory} -locatedIn-> {class:City, as: city, where: (in("locatedIn").name <> name)}
return person.name as person
```

this is the output:

[image]

as you can see only John is returned:

[image]

Hope it helps

Regards